# How to fix: Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.Runtime.dll' when trying to publish app through ClickOnce or Visual Studio Installer?

Tags: c#, winforms, clickonce, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

Have had this problem for months and I still can't seem to fix it. When running my Windows Form Application through the debugger or even through the 'Release' folder in the bin directory, the CefSharp browser works perfectly. However, when I try to publish the app through ClickOnce or even through creating a Setup file, I get this error.

Has anyone got any ideas on how to fix this? The dependencies are in the correct folders but not able to load them. I would even be open to a better "Deployment" tool if so.

Thanks!

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.Runtime.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
File name: 'CefSharp.Core.Runtime.dll'
   at CefSharp.Cef.get_IsInitialized()
   at CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser.InitializeFieldsAndCefIfRequired()
   at CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser..ctor(String address, IRequestContext requestContext)
   at EZFarm.gui.Browser.InitializeComponent()
   at EZFarm.gui.Browser..ctor()
   at EZFarm.gui.Compliance_Forms.Home.browserMenuBtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)




************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4420.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
EZFarm
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/L29/EZ%20Farm/EZFarm.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4400.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4360.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4390.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4190.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_B
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4390.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
MySql.Data
    Assembly Version: 8.0.23.0
    Win32 Version: 8.0.23.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/L29/EZ%20Farm/MySql.Data.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4270.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Transactions
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Transactions/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
----------------------------------------
Renci.SshNet
    Assembly Version: 2020.0.1.0
    Win32 Version: 2020.0.1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/L29/EZ%20Farm/Renci.SshNet.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.EnterpriseServices
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4084.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.EnterpriseServices/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.EnterpriseServices.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Management
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4435.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Management/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Management.dll
----------------------------------------
CefSharp.WinForms
    Assembly Version: 95.7.141.0
    Win32 Version: 95.7.141.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/L29/EZ%20Farm/CefSharp.WinForms.DLL
----------------------------------------
CefSharp
    Assembly Version: 95.7.141.0
    Win32 Version: 95.7.141.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/L29/EZ%20Farm/CefSharp.DLL
----------------------------------------
CefSharp.Core
    Assembly Version: 95.7.141.0
    Win32 Version: 95.7.141.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/L29/EZ%20Farm/CefSharp.Core.DLL
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

Comment: Make sure you have the same version of the dll. Can you put the whole error

Comment: I’ve just added the error details into the answer

Comment: For click once see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/discussions/3613#discussioncomment-842336 there's a set of step by step instructions a little further down.

Comment: Making it target x86 and adding in ```<CefSharpBuildAction>Content</CefSharpBuildAction>```
into the .csproj file fixed the issue